# i am making a scene from a tut and i added a cube as the volume with a principled volume shader

Tags: eevee-render-engine

soo im making a scene and i added a volume using a cube with a principled volume shader
and when i make the density to .1 its completely blank  and when i increase the density as well it just gets darker.
[image: this is before adding the volume]

this is before

[image: this is after adding the volume]

this is after adding the volume

(im using evee)

Comment: How does your volume material looks like in preview in the material menu? White as well or not? Maybe it is due to your world settings, because volume settings seems alright (maybe you should show eevee render settings as well or share your file)

Answer (score 1):

The *Emission Strength* in the *Principled Volume* node is set to 1 with a white *Emission Color*. The higher the *Density*, the more emission is blocked so it gets darker.

Comment: how do i fix it tho ? do i just change the colour ?

Comment: You set the _Emission Strength_ to 0 to get completely rid of it... or if it's intentional to emit light (don't know the tut and what they try to do there) then set it to a lower value like 0.1 or less. But of course you can set the _Emission Color_ to black as well, since black means RGB = 0, multiplied by a strength of 1 equals 0, too.